# Change the default responsive navbar breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

is there a way to change the breakpoint where Bootstrap menu becomes responsive and collapse? 979px is far too big for me and I would like the transformation taking place only on smaller sizes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by redefining `@navbarCollapseWidth` variable in `less/variables.less` file. And recompiling css after that.

Compiling instructions can be found in [Compiling Bootstrap with Less](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt) section of official documentation.

Comment: I don't have that property in my `variables.less` file with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

@nick-kugaevsky the 'compiling bootstrap with less' - link is broken.

BTW, for bootstrap 3 RC 1, you will want to modify the following property in `less/variables.less`

```
// Point at which the navbar stops collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-phone;      // here i allready changed it
```

BTW: this only prohibits the responsive nav to collapse when width > @screen-phone for example. Here is some more info on compiling bootstrap with less: http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html

You have to download bootstrap, point your app or the node js util to the bootstrap directory containing the less files, modify less/variables and recompile the bootstrap.less file.

Argh, just found out it this is written in the bootstrap documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar