# Twitter Bootstrap - Nav collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working on updating my website to be responsive using Twitter Bootstrap. My current website can be viewed @ http://www.JoshuaBock.com.

I am encountering an issue on trying to customize the Navbar collapse functionality. At the moment I have it displaying correctly, but it does not function between 981 pixels and 1126 pixels. I am avoiding modifying the Bootstrap base code so I can easily upgrade to a newer version of Bootstrap. The issue is being caused by my custom media query:

Media Query

```
<pre><code>
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1126px) {
      .navbar{
        width: 85%;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top,
      .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        position: static;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,
      .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
        padding: 5px;
      }
      .navbar .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .navbar .brand {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
      }
      .nav-collapse {
        clear: both;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > li {
        float: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > li > a {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
        display: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav .nav-header {
        color: #777777;
        text-shadow: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        padding: 9px 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #777777;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
           -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                border-radius: 3px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .btn {
        padding: 4px 10px 4px;
        font-weight: normal;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
           -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu li + li a {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover,
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #999999;
      }
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover,
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        background-color: #111111;
      }
      .nav-collapse.in .btn-group {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        display: none;
        float: none;
        max-width: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 15px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
           -moz-border-radius: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
           -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .open > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
      }
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after {
        display: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu .divider {
        display: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before,
      .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
        display: none;
      }
      .nav-collapse .navbar-form,
      .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 10px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
           -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      }
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-form,
      .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
        border-top-color: #111111;
        border-bottom-color: #111111;
      }
      .navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      .nav-collapse,
      .nav-collapse.collapse {
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .navbar .btn-navbar {
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar-static .navbar-inner {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1126px) {
        .nav-collapse.collapse{
            height:0 !important;
            overflow:hidden !important;
        }
    }

</pre></code>
```

More specify the `!important` section seems to be causing the issue. If I remove the `!important` the nav does not collapse.

The actual code can be view on my beta site @ http://beta.joshuabock.com/index.html

I know I am close to the solution, but could use some help figuring this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about "not working"?  Are you referring to the menu not collapsing the way it should do, or the fact that it's wrapping around the "Joshua Bock... Web Designer..." heading?

Comment: I am indeed referring to the meny not collapsing the way it should be. The wrapping issue will be fixed once I figure out the collapse issue, and in fact it might of been fixed already.

Comment: It looks like you've solved this now, judging by the beta link. If so could you add in your solution and close the question?

Comment: The issue is still present. When the screen is between 979px and 1126px the collapse menu will not expand when it is clicked.

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I specify media queries I normally specify them like so

```
@media all and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1126px)
```

noticed yours starts @media, so not sure if that causing any issues

Comment: That does not appear to be causing the issue.

Comment: I have found the solution to this issue. Per the comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486051/bootstrap-change-the-default-responsive-navbar-breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this

```
@media (max-width: 1992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```