# Twitter Bootstrap navbar drop down menu is not working

Tags: android, css, drop-down-menu, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a PhoneGap application where I use Bootstarp for layout and styling. The problem is that when I run the application on the Nexus 4 simulator (resolution 768x1280) Bootstrap treats it as desktop and shows the small navbar as a header, instead of the drop down menu oon the right. My index.html header is as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
```

It is mostly what was generated by PhoneGap. My aim is to bring it to this 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default the grid-float-breakpoint (defined in variables.less) is set to 768px. This means show the "desktop" (collapsed) version for all screens with a width of **>=768px**. As you mention your test screen will be inside this range.
So change the @grid-float-breakpoint to something below 768px in variables.less and recompile bootstrap (or use the [customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) to do this).

Also read http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/compile-twitters-bootstrap-3-without-responsive-features/ to see @grid-float-breakpoint does not influence all settings.

To change the dropdowns to their mobile version too, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18944192/1596547