# How to change Bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar, bootstrap-5

Currently when the browser width drops below 768px, the navbar changes to collapsed mode. I want to change this width to 1000px so when the browser is below 1000px the navbar changes to collapsed mode. I want to do this without using LESS, I am using stylus not LESS.

My issue is the same as in this question: [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse?lq=1)

But all the answers in that questions explain how to do it by changing LESS variable. I haven't been dealing with LESS, I am using stylus so I want to know how this can be done using stylus or another method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to write a specific **media query** for this, from your question, below 768px, the navbar will collapse, so apply it above 768px and below 1000px, just like that:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
}
```

This will hide the navbar collapse until the default occurrence of the bootstrap unit. As the collapse class flips the inner assets inside navbar collapse will be automatically hidden, like wise you have to set your css as you desired design.

Comment: Currently the navbar collapses when the width is below 768px. But I want the navbar to collapse when the width is below 1000px. For this, wouldn't you need to show .collapse between 768 and 1000?

Comment: yes, `collapse` class is important for mobile screen so that if width is below 768px the navbar will be `display:none`, so the required action would be applied inside 768 and 1000 mark...

Comment: this doesn't work on Bootstrap 3 because there is another rule `navbar-collapse.collapse` which has `display: block !important`. Disabling that will result in the collapse button not appearing... so I guess it's a lot of classes that needs to be redefined, not just `collapse`

Comment: Yes, a bunch of Bootstrap classes must be overridden in the custom media query: http://bootply.com/120604

Comment: Haha who the hell built bootstrap? Didn't think we would need to change that little detail?

Comment: Zim, in your code you forgot this to avoid overflow when there are to many list items: .navbar-collapse.in { overflow-y: auto !important; }

Answer (score 483):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2023)**

As [stated in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors),

> For navbars that *never* collapse, add the `.navbar-expand` class on the navbar. For navbars that *always* collapse, don’t add any `.navbar-expand` class.

---

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2018)**

Changing the navbar breakpoint is easier in Bootstrap 4 using the `navbar-expand-*` classes:

`<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm">..</nav>`

- `navbar-expand-sm` = mobile menu on xs screens <576px
- `navbar-expand-md` = mobile menu on sm screens <768px
- `navbar-expand-lg` = mobile menu on md screens <992px
- `navbar-expand-xl` = mobile menu on lg screens <1200px
- `navbar-expand` = never use mobile menu
- `(no expand class)` = always use mobile menu

If you exclude `navbar-expand-*` the mobile menu will be used at `all` widths. Here's a demo of all 6 navbar states: [Bootstrap 4 Navbar Example](http://www.codeply.com/go/n4Pn4aB695)

You can also use a custom breakpoint (???px) by adding a little CSS. For example, here's 1300px..

```
@media (min-width: 1300px){
    .navbar-expand-custom {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .nav-link {
        padding-right: .5rem;
        padding-left: .5rem;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom > .container {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-collapse {
        display: flex!important;
        flex-basis: auto;
    }
    .navbar-expand-custom .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 *Custom* Navbar Breakpoint](https://www.codeply.com/go/J70zkpygvk)
[Bootstrap 4 Navbar Breakpoint Examples](http://www.codeply.com/go/n4Pn4aB695)

---

**Bootstrap 3**

For Bootstrap 3.3.x, here is the *working* CSS to override the navbar breakpoint. Change `991px` to the pixel dimension of the point at which you want the navbar to collapse...

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

Working example for 991px: https://codeply.com/p/GxWMLj14VJ
Working example for 1200px: https://codeply.com/go/VsYaOLzfb4 (with search form)

Note: The above works for anything *over 768px*. If you need to change it to ***less than 768px*** the [example of less than 768px is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42725215/171456).

---

Comment: Try this
First Visit :[link]( http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Locate : ‘Less variables’ –> ‘Media queries breakpoints’

Change : @ screen-lg value from 1200px to 1920px

Locate : “Grid system” –> @ grid-float-breakpoint

Change : @ screen-sm-min to @ screen-lg

Scroll to end of page.

Click on “Compile and Download”

Extract and use these downloaded files.

Comment: I have many items in my navbar. I had to also add "overflow: scroll!important;" to ".collapse.in{}" definition. In bootstrap "max-height: 340px;"

Comment: This above code works when I set a value higher than 768px, however I need to achieve the reverse... I only want it to collapse for example at 400px, but when I set this value, bootstrap seems to be picking up the original 768 - Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I would add a `float:none!important` to `.navbar-text` as well if you are using it
`.navbar-left, .navbar-right, .navbar-text {
    float: none !important;
  }`

Comment: Although this answer works like charm, but it's messing with ***[dropdown menu](http://www.bootply.com/GzDUNioL5h)***, maybe you need to improve answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I've found useful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659861/1485885) (part regarding dropdown)

Comment: This solution almost worked perfectly for me. I had to add a rule for the dropdown menu as noted by others. In the parlance of the example for Bootstrap 4 above: `.navbar-expand-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {  position: absolute;  }`

Answer (score 46):

in **bootstrap3**, change this variable **@grid-float-breakpoint** to the one you need. The default value is 768px

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are using sass and you don't want to replace the vendor code (you shouldn't), you have to include the file that contains the variable with your custom value before the bootstrap sass files.

The reason being is all of Bootstrap’s variables are set to default! values, so we need to override these values by importing our variables first.

Comment: Please add an example of how to do this... I am new to bootstrap, and grep reveals 0 instances of this variable in my project.

Comment: @MattClark `@grid-float-breakpoint` is defined on the compiler: http://getbootstrap.com/customize - the default value is `@screen-sm-min` but you can change it to `1234px`.

Answer (score 25):

Finally worked out how to change the collapse width by fiddling with '@grid-float-breakpoint' at [http://getbootstrap.com/customize/](http://getbootstrap.com/customize).

Go to line 2923 in bootstrap.css(also min version) and change `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {` to `@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {`

So the code will end up being:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav.pull-right {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the line number you quoted will be different if you've used the Customizer: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Just changed the `@grid-float-breakpoint` in my `responsive.less` works for me!

Comment: You should override that in another CSS file instead of changing the bootstrap css files directly.

Comment: First Visit :[link]( http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ 

Locate : ‘Less variables’ –> ‘Media queries breakpoints’

Change : @ screen-lg value from 1200px to 1920px

Locate : “Grid system” –> @ grid-float-breakpoint

Change : @ screen-sm-min to @ screen-lg

Scroll to end of page.

Click on “Compile and Download”

Extract and use these downloaded files.

Answer (score 13):

I just did this successfully by using the following CSS code.

```
@media(max-width:1000px)  {

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        overflow-x: visible !important;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.in {
      overflow-y: auto !important;
    }

    .collapse.in {
      display: block !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't show collapsed menu button when width is anywhere between 768px to 1000px.

Comment: @craftsman : For the button, use this:   .navbar-toggle {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
  }

Comment: still does not show the content inside the hamburger menu

Answer (score 13):

In the Bootstrap 3 .LESS *source code*, there is a variable defined in `variables.less` called `@grid-float-breakpoint` which has the following helpful comment:

```
//**Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed
@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-sm-min;
```

The matching `@grid-float-breakpoint-max` value is set to that minus 1px:

```
//**Point at which the navbar begins collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint-max - 1);
```

### Solution:

So just set the `@grid-float-breakpoint` value to 1000px instead and rebuild `bootstrap.less` into `bootstrap.css`:

e.g.

```
@grid-float-breakpoint: 1000px;
```

Comment: How to rebuild ? 
I tried this command line : `$ lessc bootstrap.less bootstrap.css` but nothing happened

Comment: @AnthonyRn: I have no idea what your project setup is. I simply updated the Bootstrap LESS source in my VS 2013 project and it rebuilt on save. perhaps you should ask a new question?

Comment: My problem was solved by using the online customizer tool of Bootstrap here http://getbootstrap.com/customize 

Thank you for the solution !

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, as it uses Bootstraps own methods for defining the breakpoint.

As an example, I was able to simple 'rebuild' bootstrap, and have the desired result by setting this variable to what I needed to be the breakpoint.

Comment: @AnthonyR To Rebuild you use the grunt command `grunt dist` which will regenreate the dist directory. You will run that command from the directory where you have your gruntfile.js. Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt

Answer (score 11):

The Sass way of changing bootstrap variables is actually documented on the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) github page.

Just redefine the variables before you @import bootstrap:

```
$grid-float-breakpoint: 1000px;

@import 'bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @Skely answer, to make **dropdown menus** inside the navbar work, also add their classes to be overriden. Final code bellow:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
            position: static;
            float: none;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
        .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-toggle {
            display: block;
        }
        .navbar-collapse {
            border-top: 1px solid transparent;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none!important;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float: none!important;
            /*margin: 7.5px -15px;*/
            margin: 7.5px 50px 7.5px -15px
        }
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: none;
        }
        .navbar-nav>li>a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .navbar-text {
            float: none;
            margin: 15px 0;
        }
        /* since 3.1.0 */
        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
            display: block!important;
        }
        .collapsing {
            overflow: hidden!important;
        }
    }
```

[demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/24xpkgcv/)

Answer (score 4):

In bootstrap v4, the navigation can be collapsed sooner or later using different css classes

eg:

- navbar-toggleable-sm
- navbar-toggleable-md
- navbar-toggleable-lg

With the button for the navigation:

- hidden-sm-up
- hidden-md-up
- hidden-lg-up

Comment: In the current alpha, seems to only go to `navbar-toggleable-sm` for me, `xs` makes it never toggle. Could be me doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @nerdwaller looks like you're right, made an edit from xs to sm.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me Bootstrap3

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
          float: none;
      }
      .navbar-toggle {
          display: block;
      }
      .navbar-collapse {
          border-top: 1px solid transparent;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
      }
      .navbar-collapse.collapse {
          display: none!important;
      }
      .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
          display: block!important;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
          float: none!important;
          margin: 7.5px -15px;
      }
      .navbar-nav>li {
          float: none;
      }
      .navbar-nav>li>a {
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
}
```

Took a while to figure these two out:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
   display: none!important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
   display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. The only exception is the minimum pixel width should be 1000px in your sample above.

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 3.3 this is the only code you need:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .navbar-collapse.collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
   .navbar-toggle{
        display: block !important;
   }
   .navbar-header{
        float: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work completely. The menu items it displays are not vertical, but horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use a port of the CSS processor you use.

I'm a big fan of SASS so I currently use https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

It looks like there's a fork for Stylus here: https://github.com/Acquisio/bootstrap-stylus

Otherwise, Search & Replace is your best friend right in the css version...

Comment: So for the search & replace option, does that mean edit the bootstrap.css media queries directly? Can I change a media query that only applies to the navbar? I was told it is not a good idea to edit the source bootstrap files, but I don't know why, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you can do it using CSS like this 
you can change breakpoint bootstrap menu

```
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important; 
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    } 
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
   .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
       position: static;
       float: none;
       width: auto;
       margin-top: 0;
       background-color: transparent;
       border: 0;
       -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code for me. (Also the dropdown navbar links works)

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
 }
  .ul-links {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }  
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }

  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
      max-height: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important; 
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  } 
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
     position: static;
     float: none;
     width: auto;
     margin-top: 0;
     background-color: transparent;
     border: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick for me:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1000px){
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: With your solution and the one by Veek I'm finding that between 768 and 1000 the margins expand, improperly. They are fine outside those limits. With your solution the icon for the collapsed menu also does not stay on the right after collapsing but presses up against the "brand".

Comment: So sorry, I apparently goofed. I do still have that problem of the inappropriately-wide margins appearing inside those limits. However I see now that an official [online](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) bootstrap example exhibits the same margins problem, natively.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, if you want to over-ride when navbar-expand-*, expands and collapses and shows and hides the hamburger (navbar-toggler) you have to find that style/definition in bootstrap.css, and redefine it in your own customstyle.css (or directly in bootstrap.css if you are so inclined).

Eg. I wanted the navbar-expand-lg to collapses and shows the navbar-toggler
at 950px. In bootstrap.css I find:

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

And below that ...

```
@media (min-width:992px) { 
    ... lots of styling ...
}
```

I copied both @media queries and stuck them in my style.css, then modified the size to fit my needs. I my case I wanted it to collapse at 950px. The @media queries must need to be different sizes (I'm guessing), so I set container max-width to 949.98px and used the 950px for the other @media query and so the following code was appended to my style.css. This was not easy to detangle from twisted solutions I found on Stackoverflow and elsewhere. Hope this helps.

```
@media (max-width: 949.98px) {
    .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
    .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 950px) {
    .navbar-expand-lg {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -webkit-box-pack: start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu-right {
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-right: 0.5rem;
        padding-left: 0.5rem;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
    .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid {
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
        display: -webkit-box !important;
        display: -ms-flexbox !important;
        display: flex !important;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
        flex-basis: auto;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-expand-lg .dropup .dropdown-menu {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my working code using in React with Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .navbar-collapse.collapse {
       display: none !important;
   }
   .navbar-toggle{
        display: block !important;
   }
   .navbar-header{
        float: none;
   }
}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's now supported on Bootstrap 4.4

```
navbar-expand-sm
```

Comment: Yes correct, but you would need navbar-expand-lg to collapse the nav on large screens