# Bootstrap navbar collapse media-query on custom width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

Helo guys, I want to modify the navbar in order to collapse on `@screen-md :992px;`.
I have modified `navbar.less`, but still not working and I don't know what to do.

So how can I modify the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in order to have that menu collapsed on custom media query size?

**[FIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/1244/)**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can change the collapse point in 3.1 like this..

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/120951

---

In **Bootstrap 4**, changing the breakpoint is easier. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289507/171456)

Comment: Finally a solution that works properly for v3 (or, at least 3.3)!!

Comment: Just a very little objection: as medium devices START at 992px, shouldn't the media query be set at a MAX width of 991px?

Answer (score 2):

In `variables.less` change

```
@grid-float-breakpoint:   @screen-sm-min
```

to

```
@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-md-min;
```

or to whatever other width you would like.

It's easy and painless done this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I used to solve this, just add it to your style sheet.

```
@media (max-width: 1992px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this CSS works to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, the responsive collapse is already built in. You may just have to invoke it with a class in your menu. But this is the css I use in most of the Bootstrap applications I've worked with, including the one I working in right now

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
   .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    /* more code here */
}
```

change the min width to the width you want it to collapse from.

Comment: try to put your media query into my fiddle width min width:1200px:| Not working.

Comment: Technically I said the same as the answer above only I didn't work out the code for you, because you're supposed to do that on your own. But ok, the important thing is you got it worked out

Comment: I was looking for an answer and not a hint. thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news but we are not supposed to be giving you the answer. It could be homework. But in general, if you dont get your gears turning, you'll never figure it out. One true fact about developing = Spend 1 hour creating and 7 debugging :) cheers