# Change Navbar breakpoint in Bootstrap 3.3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting together a rough navbar using Twitter bootstrap.

[image: TopNav1]

There's a breakpoint at which the width of the device will cause the navbar items to collapse and show a menu button instead:

[image: TopNav3]

How can I change the breakpoint so the navbar collapses sooner? At the moment its able to break on to a new line when it comes up against the logo, which doesn't look too great:

[image: TopNav2]

I've tried a fix detailed [here](https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint), but it seemed to break the collapsed menu (couldn't expand it again afterwards).

Here's the html:

```
    <!-- navigation -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="ManeEventLogo" src="/img/ManeEventLogoWhite-Sm.png"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/index.php">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">SERVICES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/services/cutting-styling/index.php">Cutting & Styling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/services/coloring/index.php">Coloring</a></li>                                
                                <li><a href="/services/hair-straightening-relaxing/index.php">Permanent Hair Straightening & Relaxing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/services/balmain-hair-extensions/index.php">Balmain Hair Extensions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/wedding-day/index.php">WEDDING DAY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/expertise-team/index.php">THE EXPERTISE TEAM</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/photo-gallery/index.php">PHOTO GALLERY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/blog/index.php">BLOG</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Which version of bootstrap are you using? 3.1? Anyway, I need as well your css to help you to fix it, but generally:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
   .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
       position: static;
       float: none;
       width: auto;
       margin-top: 0;
       background-color: transparent;
       border: 0;
       -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       box-shadow: none;
    }
}
```

The max width is the breakpoint. Copied from [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/120604) (with demo included there).

Comment: That's mostly worked.. thank you. There's an issue with the "Services" item, which has a drop-down menu attached to it. When the navbar is collapsed and then expanded through the menu button, the "Services" drop-down expands in the same way it did prior to the navbar being collapsed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm lost, could you give me a link or printscreen? I don't know, what do you exactly want to, but you can change behavior of it the same way, just put your css into `@media (max-width: 1200px) {}` and that's all

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7jLm8btr/ Resize the browser width until the navbar collapses to the menu button, then try to open the "Services" drop-down. Notice the drop-down menu is floating on top of everything.. normal behaviour would be for it to expand under the "Services" item.

Comment: @MattHall It looks fine to me - dropdown is opened below "Sevices" content, see prinscreen [link](https://www.uploady.com/download/pfP44GxpOCD/jIesiEZxjm37j5J5)

Comment: Weird.. it's not working properly on my local version: [link](https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/OHX0bE0cYGF/zLmIqbcUAIeTsfqO)

Comment: @MattHall try to explore using inspector what is applied to your sub menu, there has to be something making the mess.

Comment: ahh.. it seems to do it in the fiddle when you actually trigger the break-point. So if the navbar is already collapsed it won't do it.. try expanding and collapsing the navbar by resizing your browser, then you should see what I'm seeing.

Comment: @MattHall Here you go, I've edited my answer, code for _.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu_ need to be included as well. You can probably mark it as correct answer. ;)

Comment: @kybernaut-cz that's done the trick! thank you :)

Comment: there seems to be a problem with overflow

Comment: @don_Bigote where? Could you send me a bootply link where I can see it? Are you sure, that you didn't mixed it with bootply rendering issue (you need to click for smaller wides)

Comment: @kybernaut.cz I am sure that the problem is with your code and not bootply. I tried it on my local machine. The problem is that if you add more `<li>` tags then you can't scroll to view the content in the `<li>` tags. You need to add this to make it work: `.navbar-nav {
      max-height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll!important;
  }`

Comment: Awesome @@kybernaut.cz! Works like a charm!

Comment: I had some issues with the menu going open and closes again directly after. Fixed this by adding:  .navbar-collapse.collapse.in: display: block!important;

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a navbar breakpoint at 991 px. The .navbar-nav class is important if you have more than a few links in your navbar.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;

      max-height: 300px;
      overflow-y: scroll!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }

}
```