# bootstrap3 make menu collapse sooner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've seen similar questions but not the one that will help me..

I'm using Bootstrap 3 (without less) I would like the menu to collapse sooner like around 999px

Here's the basic code I'm using:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <!--  <span class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">German Magic Farm</span> -->
          <img class="visible-xs" src="img/german-magic-farm-logo-sm.png" width="93" height="102" alt="German Magic Farm Logo" longdesc="index.html">
        <img class="hidden-xs" src="img/german-magic-logo-sm-bars.png" width="110" height="133" alt="German Magic Farm Logo" longdesc="index.html"></a>
        
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="meet-pam-bauer.html">Meet Pam Bauer</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                   <li>
                    <a href="sales.html">Sales</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="clinics.html">Clinics</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="photo-gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="contact.html"> Directions & Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

My test site is here:  [Test Site](http://www.amystout.com/germanmagic/index.html)

Since I have not been able to figure out a way to move the text in the 'whole nav bar' over to the right a little more on viewports of about 1000 I thought maybe changing the brake point of the collapse might be easier...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This thread leads to a solution in @Skelly's comment on the accepted answer. [Change bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint without using LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19827605/4946307)

The comment attaches a [Bootply](http://bootply.com/120604) in which all of the necessary css classes/media-queries are overridden. Just change the media query in the css from `1200px` to `1000px` or which ever makes the most sense in your case.

Comment: Oh I did see that post but someone further down said it wouldn't work for Bootstrap 3.   That was why I asked anyway... so now I don't know what to do...??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the navbar to the right, you should make this change:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
.navbar-nav{
margin-left:20%;
}
}
```

Otherwise, the breaking point thing is answered in the other question as it's mentioned in the comment of Mr. Kumar.

Comment: Thank you is there a way I can just center the text in the collapsed menu?

Comment: You just make the navbar-nav have the property `text-align:center;` , or else, if you want that the text stay as is and just look somehow centered, you can increase the margin-left to be 40% , I just tried it and it'll look great for your website.You don't have to write it under a media query though.But if you want to add @media (max-width: 768px), that'll do the job as well..

Comment: OH my gosh, thank you, yep I totally knew I could use the text-align:center but I ftp-ed (is that a verb lol) over a few different ways today to no avail, very frustrating because it worked great in develop tools... I so appreciate your help, I will try in the morning ;-)

Comment: Happy that I was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add .navbar-right  `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`