# How can I collapse my navigation sooner? Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to collapse this navigation before it breaks the line. What can I do to help with this?  Also I have commented out the navbar-tab which is just an image fixed to the top (should also collapse).

```
 Here's the link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skc97fyz/4/).
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with an css media query

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) { 
    .collapse {
       display: none !important;  
     }
    }
```

More information can be found in this post:
[Change bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint without using LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less)

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Now the navbar-toggle is jumping about. Is there a way to fix the position of it? always 20px from the right for example?

Comment: With a mobile query you can give it a position absolute :)