# How to modify bootstrap3 navbar's responsive dimensions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap3 navbar and I'm having this problem when I decrease the screen resolution:

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20DaW.png)

You can see that because of the number of elements that the navbar has, when I decrease the screen resolution, the elements that are aligned to the right, are passed down.

I need to avoid that, that is, this:

[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7jjw.png)

should occur instead the problem I showed.

The navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Las Holass</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Hooola Holaaa!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">holahola</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hooola hola!</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-hover" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Holita
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="login" href="#">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hooola Holas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">hoola holaaa</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- fin navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- fin container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Is there a way to define the width in pixels from which the toggle-navigation button will appear?

For example, between 0px and 890px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the navbar breakpoint from 1000px to the desired breakpoint, where you want navbar to collapse

```html
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

refernce https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289507/3615004

Comment: ty so much, I just added this media query to my style.css and works.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this variable and make a custom version of Bootstrap for you, just go to the [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system). You need variable "@grid-float-breakpoint" at the "Grid system" section.

Comment: is there a posibility to do that in bootstrap.min.css file or another bootstrap file from css folder?

Answer (score 0):

It's set up using media queries in the bootstrap.min.css file (or bootstrap.css file if you're not using the minified version).

if you look through the file, you'll see a lot of the nav stuff is wrapped in `@media (min-width:768px){}`. I'd start with adjusting the pixels on the media query, or I'd take the nav stuff out of the media query and put it into my own stylesheet so I can adjust the media query accordingly and not affect anything else that may have been wrapped in the `@media (min-width:768px){}`.