# Bootstrap Navbar collapse point < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is an OLD question for Bootstrap 3 -> changing the collapse point for the navbar, but the methodologies suggested here:

https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint

and here:

[Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

do not work for collapsing below **768px**, it only seems to work for extending the collapse point, not retracting it.  I have a particular situation where my navbar has 3 buttons, so it doesn't need to collapse so early.  I would like it to collapse at 420px instead.

Is there a CSS solution to this?  If not, can somebody point me towards the correct attribute in the bootstrap customisation page which I need to change and download?  Is it the generic breakpoints perhaps?  Because there is nothing I can see which says Navbar breakpoints:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

As requested, my HTML for the navbar is simply:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id = "navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class = "navbar_buttons"><a id = "new_route_button"><strong>New Route</strong></a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li class = "navbar_buttons"><a id = "clear_route_button">Clear Route</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    <!--Right justified navbar list-->
                <li class = "navbar_buttons"><a id = "about_button">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>  <!-- Container -->

</nav>  <!-- End of Navbar Container -->
```

Then I have some CSS to add a vertical division:

```
/*Preventing vertical dividers from appearing collapsed*/
@media (max-width: 420px) {
.navbar-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
    display: none;
  }
}

/*Defining the vertical dividers*/
.navbar .divider-vertical {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 9px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
  border-right-color: #222222;
  border-left-color: #111111;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Yes of course, I'll edit imminently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, changing the breakpoint to anything *less than 768px* is different than [changing the breakpoint over 768px](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289507/171456). You need to override all of the Bootstrap defaults that normally make it collapse.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    .collapse {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar-nav.navbar-left {
       float: left;
       margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
       float: right;
       margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: left;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
     .collapse {
        display: none;
     }

     .navbar-header {
        display: block;
     }
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/wpUuFIZqJ2

Comment: Almost perfect, there must be something missing though, as my navbar has a left and right aligned content, and the right aligned content moves over to the left after 767px.

Comment: I have edited your answer with a correction to account for the separation of navbar-right and navbar-left.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ZimSystem your CSS above did not work for me, but the CSS you posted at http://www.bootply.com/qL4jyCx5sE did work.

Comment: @ZimSystem In line 21 there should be a 1 px different in `min-width` versus `max-width` line 2 and line 50 as otherwise at exactly 420px the menu is completely invisible, no normal menu, no mobile menu.
Like so:
`@media only screen and (min-width: 421px) {`

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is based on the original answer, but also works when there are drop down menus in the navbar.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  @media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
    .collapse {
      display: block;
    }
    .navbar-header {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar>.container .navbar-brand,
    .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: -15px;
    }
    .container>.navbar-header,
    .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
    .container>.navbar-collapse,
    .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
      margin-right: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
      float: right;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      float: left;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 2px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
      background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      color: #333;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
      line-height: 1.42857143;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
      padding: 3px 20px;
    }
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
      right: 0;
      left: auto;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 559px) {
    .collapse {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-header {
      display: block;
    }
  }
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```