# Responsive menu inline with wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Currently working on a redesign of a theme based from: [Educampus](https://themeforest.net/item/educampus-education-university-wordpress-theme/12092865)

I'm having a problem where the responsive menu goes to two lines on a certain size:

```
col-lg or col-md:
```

[image]

```
col-sm
```

[image]

```
col-xs
```

[image]

For this I have the following code (after generated by wordpress through `wp_nav_menu`):

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lfhs1jb/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="header_content">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="logo">
               <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/Random_App_Logo.png" alt=""></a>
               <div class="navbar-header rowl">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 nav_area">
         <nav class="main_menu navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-25 current_page_item menu-item-92 active"><a title="Welcome" href="http://imagerylab.pixiumdigital.com/">myLongerLongTitle</a></li>
               <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-107 dropdown">
                  <a title="Researches" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">myLongTitle <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                     <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-129"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-130"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-131"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-132"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-133"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-114 dropdown">
                  <a title="Publications" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">myLongerLongTitle <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
                     <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-187"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-188"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                     <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-189"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li id="menu-item-257" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-257"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
               <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106"><a title="myTitle" href="#">myTitle</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
         <form action="#" class="header_search hidden-xs">
            <input placeholder="Search" value="" name="s" id="s" type="text">
            <input value="Search" type="submit">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header_content {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e4e4e4;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.logo{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.logo a img {
    min-width: 200px !important;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.nav_area {
    padding-right: 88px;
}
li{
  background-color:#c0c0c0;
  border: solid thin white;
}
```

I also tried the following solution but the text gets cut:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/f4bpyav4/

Modified CSS:

```
.header_content {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e4e4e4;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.logo{
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.logo a img {
    min-width: 200px !important;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.nav_area {
    padding-right: 88px;
}
li{
  background-color:#c0c0c0;
  border: solid thin white;
}
#menu-main-menu{
     list-style: none;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: visible !important;
}
#menu-main-menu > li{
    display: inline-block;
     width: 17%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0;
}
#menu-main-menu > li > a{
    font-size: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the theme is using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-default) css framework as its foundation.

You've got a couple of options:

- Increase the size at which the mobile view (with the hamburger menu) triggers.
- Decrease the margins & font sizes on the smaller sizes.
- Hide menu items.

All of these options can be achieved with css [Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/#article-header-id-1).
ZimSystems [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289507/1203738) describes how to do option 1.

The same hold true when using media queries to decrease the fontsize/margins:
(resize the browser *after going fullscreen* to trigger different css rule sets, `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 420px)` )

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 420px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav li a {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom:0px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  div.navbar {
    min-height: 30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  .collapse {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .collapse {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it still doesn't fit, you can hide (redundant) menu items.
 IE  `.navbar .navbar-nav li:nth-child(2){display:none;}`

There is only so much space you can use. If you can't fit an elephant into a closet. you ether get a bigger closet or a smaller elephant.

Comment: Like I said I want it on one inline block not triggering the hamburger menu until the col-xs.

However I have tried reducing margin and font but I still get some overflowing text on those smaller sizes

Comment: If you have already reduced font-size and margin, iI think you have no more options than Lars answers.