# .col-xxl create personal breakpoints

Tags: bootstrap-5

For a personal project (dashboard) I have setup a simple columns layout using bootstrap. The columns of one of the rows I have given the followings classes: col-xxl-2 col-lg-4 col-sm-6

- gt 1400px: 6 columns
- gt 992px: 3 columns
- gt 567px: 2 columns

This works fine, I was however hoping to change the breakpoint for "xxl" to something higher than 1400px since 6 columns is just a bit too much on 1500 something pixels. Is this possible?

I'm using container-fluid for my main container btw.

Comment: It's possible with SASS

Comment: Unfortunately my hosting provider does not support SASS.

Comment: It's not a hosting thing. It's compiling from SASS to CSS. If you can't use SASS it's not really possible without a lot of extra CSS. It would require using [media queries like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less)

Comment: Ok. Think I’ll until they implement even larger screens then. No worries since it’s only a tinker project.

Comment: yea i have same question...  Why there is no "row-cols-xxl-11" in bootstrap 5.1? I mean after "row-cols-xxl/xl/lg/md/sm/xs-6" , there is no 7 8 9 10 11 12....