# Auto-close collapsed R Shiny navbarPage

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, navbar

I have an R Shiny app with a collapsed `navbarPage` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359101/4112892).
Now I would appreciate to have the menu collapsing on its own as soon as the cursor moves away from it rather than collapsing it manually.
I have seen a [couple of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248194/close-responsive-navbar-automatically) for other frameworks, but does someone know how to solve this with R Shiny?

A simple example app here:

```
library(shiny)

navbar_js <- "@media (max-width: 12000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}"

ui <- navbarPage("App title",
                 collapsible = TRUE,
                 tabPanel("Panel 1"),
                 tabPanel("Panel 2"),
                 tabPanel("Panel 3"),
                 tags$head(tags$style(HTML(navbar_js))))

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time and many JavaScript lessons later, I figured out how to write a jQuery snippet that hides the extended navbar when (i) clicking onto a link within the navbar (but still opens toggle menus inside the navbar) and (ii) clicking anywhere outside the navbar. :)

```
library(shiny)

navbar_js <- "@media (max-width: 12000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}"


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script("// Autoclose navbar
                $(document).click(function (event) {
                  // after click into navbar
                  if ($(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse a:not(.dropdown-toggle)')) {
                    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
                  }
                  // after click anywhere outside navbar
                  if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {
                    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
                  }
                });")
  ),
  navbarPage("App with autocollapsing navbar :)",
             collapsible = TRUE,
             tabPanel("Panel 1"),
             tabPanel("Panel 2"),
             navbarMenu("Panel 3",
                        tabPanel("Panel 3a"),
                        tabPanel("Panel 3b")),
             tabPanel("Panel 4"),
             tags$head(tags$style(HTML(navbar_js))))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```