# Stop element wrapping in bootstrap nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `bootstrap-navbar` which is wrapping onto two lines below a certain width, is there any way to stop it doing this without hacking around in the bootstrap LESS file?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"> <span class="navbar-brand">Brand</span></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a id="btn-dashboard" class="navbar-link">Items&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span class="badge">1</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Example at: http://jsfiddle.net/u10Lvgk8/2/

If you reduce the page width on the project above, you'll see the menu wraps onto two lines, even though the elements are very small! Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bootstrap limitation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Bootstrap 3 navbar going 2 rows in medium viewport size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012665/disable-bootstrap-3-navbar-going-2-rows-in-medium-viewport-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice when the screen is larger than 768px bootstrap specific styles take into effect.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
}
```

You can change those in your own CSS (without overloading the vendor stylesheets) because of the way CSS works. As long as **your stylesheet is linked AFTER bootstrap's** your CSS rules will have a higher precedence than Bootstrap's. Meaning, your styles can override bootstrap's.

So you would just change these to:

Something like:

```
@media (min-width: 460px)
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 460px)
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u10Lvgk8/2/

Comment: @pseudological happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this using CSS. Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
.navbar-header {
    float:left;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u10Lvgk8/4/

Comment: This is good advice, I gave you a vote but gave the answer point to @Schultzie since the !important tags were required in my case. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You didnt close the span having class navbar-brand properly..
this(>) is missing

and for lower screenwidth bootstrap automatically drops the right navbar to bottom, you can hide it by Collapsing The Navigation Bar as,

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 .navbar-right{
  float: right !important;
     margin-right: -15px !important;
 }
 .navbar{border-radius:4;}
 .container-fluid>.navbar-header{    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;}
 .navbar-header {
    float: left;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <span class="navbar-brand">Brand</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a id="btn-dashboard" class="navbar-link">Items&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge">1</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I didn't, good spot :). I'm not looking for a collapse to a hamburger style menu, I don't see why I should have to when the button is clearly small enough to fit on the same line without collapsing!

Comment: @pseudological.. I have changed the code.. maybe this will help you..:D