# Preventing navigation menu to wrap

Tags: html, css

The navigation menu of my website (www.maranto.eu) wraps to a second line on Chrome on my laptop. It doesn't happen on the same device on IE neither on Chrome on my desktop. I've tried to delete my cache, to set the display:inline property and to find a solution throught forums but I have been unable to figure out the right code to put into. What can I do to fix the problem?Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show relevant code directly inside the question (otherwise it will loose all value to future readers, if you fix the issue on your website, and therefor the problem will become irreproducible.)

Comment: That being said, if you simply stop floating `.edgtf-vertical-align-containers .edgtf-position-right`, that seems to fix the issue already.

Comment: Try this, maybe it's your problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024897/6503551

Comment: @CBroe  Sorry, it's my first question and I didn't know. I'll try to post relevant code next time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `:before` , which is causing the last li not to fit on the same line as the others. I don't know the reason why that before is there , but if you overwrite it , the problem goes away

```
.edgtf-vertical-align-containers .edgtf-position-center:before, .edgtf-vertical-align-containers .edgtf-position-left:before, .edgtf-vertical-align-containers .edgtf-position-right:before {
    content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
        margin-right: -3px;
    }
```

just use display:none on it.

Comment: glad i could help ! :D