# Bootstrap collapsible nav at 1280px screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently including bootstrap in my project with bootstrapcdn.com and have a seperate file that handles all my custom CSS. For some reason I'm having issues choosing when the navigation bar will collapse. It currently collapses at 766px wide, but need it to collapse at 1280px wide (standard window size). Any idea what I should place in my custom css file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Comment: @Blazemonger I need to do this without using less or sass. just pure css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS solution using media queries would be something like this..

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98488)

Comment: I tried this. Don't think it's overriding bootstrap's default css.

Comment: Since the default collapse point it 768px.. you're right it's not overriding it.. but will achieve what you want by getting the nav to collapse sooner at 1280px

Comment: It wont collapse at 1280px though. Only 768px. Even with the CSS you posted.

Comment: It does for me.. Open http://bootply.com/render/98488 and resize your browser. Watch the "current viewport width" and the collapsed nav.

Comment: It didn't work because I had the custom css stated before the bootstrapcdn. Thank you for your answer. Works like a charm!