# Change bootstrap 3 sass toggle point

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 with rails and I want to change the toggle point, 
there is a thread for less [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse) but nothing for sass.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

This one worked for me.
Example:

```
$screen-xs-min: 240px;
$screen-sm-min: 384px;
$screen-md-min: 496px;
$screen-lg-min: 600px;

@import "bootstrap";
```

So, essentially, put any variables you want to overwrite before `@import "bootstrap"`. 
 [Bootstrap3 customize page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) is helpful to find particular varibales you want, and replace `@`with `$` when you use it in a sass context.