# Boostrap 3.0 add custom grid breakpoint

Tags: grid

Bootstrap 3 supports a gridsystem. But there is a gapp between 480px and 768px. Does anybody knows how to add a custom breakpoint between xs and sm.

I was thinking something like this:

1. xs < 480
2. ti 480 - 768
3. sm > 768
4. md >992
5. lg > 1200

Comment: Could you please clarify? That is rather ambiguous at this time.

Comment: In bootstrap 3 there is a grid system. And there is a gapp (breakpoint) between 480 and 768.

Because now there is xs and sm. I want a breakpoint between those. So is there a way to add a custom breakpoint

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817956/change-collapse-breakpoint-in-bootstrap-3-0 ; As for the gap, what type of devices are you looking to support in that range? Can't think of anything off the top of my head that belongs within it. xs is rated for phones, and sm is rated for tablets.

Comment: No this is not what iam looking for i wil try to find an example on Google

Comment: Here is what a mening https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10203 there they talk about a gist but i dont know how to use it

Comment: It explains how to go through and install it in the comments, I would suggest checking them out.

Comment: I have looked through the comments and cant see how to Install and use it