# Bootstrap Navbar resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I’m using the business casual bootstrap, but I have a problem with the navbar.  I’ve had more links and now when I resize to a smaller screen  it shows two lines in the NavBar, only resizing more ends up collapsing. Can you please advise how to fix this problem.

Comment: please post your code and preferably a fiddle or bootply

Answer (score 0):

navbar collapsing point depends on predefined in bootstrap breakpoint. Easy way, try to change padding of menu elements:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px)
    .nav>li>a {
    padding: 35px;
    }
```

in business-casual.css line 150,

or try to change that breakpoint: [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse?lq=1)