# Bootstrap 3 - show collapsed navigation for all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v3.

I have the navbar classes in place so that when I have my screen mobile-size the navigation collapses and the little grid-like toggle button appears - so this is working as expected.

what i would like, is for this to be the default action for all screen sizes. That is, even on a desktop I would like the navigation to be collapsed and the toggle button to be visible.

I've had a look through the css and there is a whole bunch of stuff that provides the functionality, though I don't know which parts to change.

I've tried commenting out the larger media-queries, though there are a lot of them and it seems to have a knock-on effect to other styling.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a link to the website?

Comment: Nope, sorry, internal site. Though if you see the standard bootstrap nav-bar - that's whats being used. Just need to have the nav-bar collapsed for all media sizes

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use override the default Bootstrap CSS like this...

```
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/114896

This will ensure that the collapsed navbar is always used by overriding the Bootstrap @media queries.

**Update:** For Bootstrap 4, you just need to remove the `navbar-toggleable` class:
http://www.codeply.com/go/LN6szcJO53

Comment: Thanks - that did it for me. I get a weird thick grey bar at the bottom of the nav while its animating, though i'm sure i can figure that part.

Comment: this works well for bootstrap 3.0.3. After moving to 3.3.2 it needed this added to the css: .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {display: block !important; } . Otherwise when expanded, it would immed collapse.

Comment: @puddleglum where did you use that css though? You need display:none to initially hide the .navbar-collapse.collapse

Comment: @Rich - starting with skelly's answer above I just added it at the end and kept it all in a separate css file.

Answer (score 10):

This is what worked for me.

Visit : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Locate : 'Less variables' --> 'Media queries breakpoints'

Change : @screen-lg value from 1200px to 1920px

Locate : "Grid system" --> @grid-float-breakpoint

Change : @screen-sm-min to @screen-lg

Scroll to end of page.

Click on "Compile and Download"

Extract and use these downloaded files.

Comment: This fix is a bit wild.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
```

If suppose you find problems with toggle too, then put the following:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
    display: block!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way i found is to change the variable.less file and change

```
// Navbar collapse
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-sm-min;
```

to

```
// Navbar collapse
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:     ( your break point );
```

Only if you use LESS ofc.

Comment: With the grid-float-breakpoint at 100%, it NEVER collapses. This is the opposite of what they wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to save time but it wasn't perfect. I got some issues with latest bootstrap, there is some unnecessary code and has a `overflow` problem in the drop-down menu. This code was the best solution for me:

```
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding 100% value on `@grid-float-breakpoint` (Grid system -> `@grid-float-breakpoint` -> `100%` instead of `@screen-sm-min`).

Comment: Might want to add some explanation