# Bootstrap 3.2 - Show Collapsed Navigation for All Screen Sizes - Dropdown Menu Disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and am trying to show the toggle button and collapsed navigation for all screen sizes. I added the custom CSS from this solution:

[Bootstrap 3 - show collapsed navigation for all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860263/bootstrap-3-show-collapsed-navigation-for-all-screen-sizes)

But unfortunately, immediately after the drop down menu appears, it disappears. The solution works for Bootstrap version 3.0.3, but with versions 3.1.0, 3.1.1 and 3.2.0, the menu immediately disappears.

You can see an example here: http://www.bootply.com/OS6ruSGi6Q

I've tested all of the CSS styles, so I'm assuming that this is a bootstrap javascript issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following to your css:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
}
```

works for me

Comment: Yep, that works. Somehow I didn't try that before. Appreciate the help on that!