# Make 3 lines menu for large screens

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

[image: 3 line Menu Image]

There are 4 links that would be displayed when someone clicks on 3 line menu Button in given image.
My problem is that this menu works for small screen. I want to override  this feature by displaying it at large screen like 767px etc.  I am confused that where i should what piece of code in my css file.
Help me!

Css_File

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.navbar-default[role="transparent_navbar"] 
{

  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #787878;
  border-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #787878;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider {
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffb600;
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #5e5b60;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #6ecd6e;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffb600;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #6ecd6e;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffb600;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffb600;
    background-color: #5e5b60;
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to show the 3 line menu button in all size screen?

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860263/bootstrap-3-show-collapsed-navigation-for-all-screen-sizes),
Write the following style in your custom css without using media query. This code will override media query and will show the 3 line menu button in all screen size

```
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
  display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: Your code did not work. As it causes to collapse menu automatic when once opens

Comment: alright, maybe you will have change something in html also. check this demo http://www.bootply.com/114896

Comment: see my shared answer

Comment: great. I also found a solution. Just needed to add display block.

Comment: I've edited my code and tested. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to:

- Display the full navbar on screens with a width of `767px` or more .
- Display the three lines on screens with a width under `767px`.

  ```
  @media (min-width: 767px)
    // add style for full navbar

  @media (max-width: 767px)
    // add style for 3-line navbar
  ```

Comment: I have attached all of my css in my question. Would you please like to tell me that which part is showing 3 line menu. Because i am new on bootstrap and css.

Comment: You need to enter the style for the 3-line menu in `@media (max-width: 767px)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone for spending their precious time.
I found the correct answer from the link below

https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint

I implemented the below css code and found the solution exactly what i was searching for.

Code

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jasny's Plugin for this followed by this link:- [Jasny Plugin For Offcanvas Bootstrap Menu](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/#navmenu-offcanvas)