# Bootstrap 3- make vetical navbar not pushing site content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create side navbar which do not interact with site content( not move content). Example bootstrap 3 navbar from one of sites:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/side-menu-on-hover

I know that in the Internet or forum must be corespondent post but i cant find it. I ask for advice/link or example of above navbar to make it not pushing content.

Comment: If the navbar doesn't push the content, some of the content will disapear behind the navbar. Or do you want a fixed navbar like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: Yes, i want hide for a while content behind sliding navbar. I dont need fixed navbar,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the navbar to the absolute top left using CSS, it will not push the content:

```
.navbar {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

If you want this to happen on desktop only, put the rule set inside a media query like this:

```
@media (min-width: 765px) {
    .navbar {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
}
```

If you want to show the hamburger menu (show/hide menu) on all screen sizes (also desktop), have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860263/bootstrap-3-show-collapsed-navigation-for-all-screen-sizes).

Comment: Great! It works perfect but i need to add z-index to navbar. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. If your content uses a z-index value, the navbar needs a z-index greater than the content.