# How to keep Bootstrap 3 navbar as collapsed for all screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3, I want the navbar to be collapsed by default for all screen sizes.

I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse?lq=1) that Bootstrap 3 being mobile first, its navbar is "collapsed" by default and and "expands" when it reaches a certain minimum size.. Following that post, I tried messing around with `@grid-float-breakpoint` for [customized css](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), but I got nowhere. Please guide me from here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use CSS to override the **Bootstrap 3** defaults.  For example, this would set the navbar to collapse on screen widths less than 2000 pixels (accommodating most screens)..

```
@media (max-width: 2000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/122572

---

**Update for Bootstrap 4 (beta)**

In Bootstrap 4 the navbar is *always collapsed* into the mobile/hamburger version by default: [Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/LN6szcJO53/bootstrap-4-navbar-always-collapsed). The `navbar-expand-*` class are used to change the breakpoint.

Comment: yours is working fine however, it's occupying the whole width. do you know how to set the width when you expand? and it should be on the right side only

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You'd change the 2000 accordingly to toggle the horizontal menu/collapsed menu