# How to keep navigation bar collapsed on all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried these two different solutions suggested here on SO :

- [How to keep Bootstrap 3 navbar as collapsed for all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462142/how-to-keep-bootstrap-3-navbar-as-collapsed-for-all-screen-sizes#22463254)
- [Change bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint without using LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less)

I've also tried many other different solutions suggesting more or less the same. None worked for me.

How can I keep Bootstrap 3 navigation bar collapsed on all screen sizes, both big and small?

This is the HTML :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
             <img class="img-responsive imglogoheader" src="images/logo1.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class=""><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
         <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
      <ul style="display:none !important;" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested in this SO Post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092929/where-to-edit-bootstrap-grid-float-breakpoint>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer suggested by tao worked at 60% but not all the way for me. Here I share what finally did it for me. In my **custom.css** I override bootstrap with custom rules

custom.css

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-header,
  .navbar .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .collapsing {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

I had to comment out this line in `bootstrap.min.cs` to make it all work :

```
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    /* display:block!important;*/
     height:auto!important;
     padding-bottom:0;
     overflow:visible!important
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the navbar menu toggle-able on all responsive intervals in Bootstrap 3, you need this snippet:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    .navbar-header,
    .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
      float: none;
      margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
      float: none;
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
      display: block;
    }
    .collapsing {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note it's SCSS. If you want it as CSS, you could copy/paste it from the demo at the end of the answer.

The solution is largely adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617020/1891677) but I thought it's worth posting it as a clean one rather then telling you to play with breakpoints and clean it up.
Most importantly, it doesn't use `!important`.

Feel free to upvote the original answer. It is an exceptional solution to a difficult problem, especially considering the complexity of Bootstrap 3's navbar collapse logic mechanics (it's done by the collapse plugin, in JavaScript - which makes it difficult to debug and/or reverse engineer).

See it working:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-header,
  .navbar .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .collapsing {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
             Logo
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse .navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class=""><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just tried it but for some reason the behavior I get is a constant opened navigation bar as if I had already clicked on it. In your example, the navigation is closed by default which is the normal behavior but in my app the navigation is opened. Do I make any sense? Do you have idea why?

Comment: @SaturnConjuction, it sounds like you have custom CSS causing it. Obviously, I can't tell you the cause without having a look. I'm human :)
Find a way to reproduce it and I'll probably find a fix.