# Bootstrap collapse nav at 991px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Building a site using Bootstrap. Having an issue with the van. I want it to collapse at 991px. Searched online and found this code, however it has changed the function of the nav as the nav wont stay open. Any ideas? The code used to override default is in my custom.css

http://nurdit.com/styleengineered/

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the CSS above to:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

   .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {  /* NEW */
        display: block!important; 
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this does the trick on your site. Credit for this suggestion goes to [Dave Forber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892940/dave-forber) , see [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Comment: Thanks so so much, that was a massive massive massive help