# Twitter bootstrap 3 how to activate navbar-collapse on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and working on a mobile site. I'm trying to figure out how to show and activate navbar-toggle on viewing tablet devices (Small / SM Device) because the navbar-collapse only works at Extra small devices . There is no problem while using bootstrap 2

heres my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default-top" role="navigation" style="border:0px; background:#F26522;" align="center">

    <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:#fff; height:192px;" align="center" > 

<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div><a  href="#"><img src="logo_png.png"   class="img-responsive" ></a></td>
   </div>


    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12"">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-12">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class="sr-only ">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button> 

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navr">
              <li class="navrli"><a href="#" id="nav-0">ABOUT</a> </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-sm" align="right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 

  <!-- /.container --> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Include markup, please.

Comment: you can do this by customizing the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable as instructed in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) (_Overflowing content_ section, point _c._)

Comment: i included the markup. thanks

Comment: you have malformed HTML on line 9 of your example:

 `div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12""> <--`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, the breakpoint is `@screen-sm-min` (ie ≥768px).

[View an Example](http://jsbin.com/xumad/2/edit?html,output)

### Customize the navbar breakpoint

To customize the navbar breakpoint, change the less variable `@grid-float-breakpoint`.

From the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar):

> ### Overflowing content
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> ...
>
> **c.** Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the **@grid-float-breakpoint** variable or add your own media query.

You can use [Bootstrap's customization tool](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to build a modified version of Bootstrap. From [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system), you can alter `@grid-float-breakpoint` to another breakpoint defined by Bootstrap (ie, `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`) or a set amount (ie `500px`).

When you're finished, navigate to the [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#download) section, and click [<kbd>Compile and Download</kbd>](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#download)

**Edit**

Your markup works as expected, as well: http://jsbin.com/kuxah/1/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks for the help! i really appreciate :) but basically i just really need to show the navbar toggle and collapse until 991px screen. i will try to follow your suggestions :)

Comment: I explain how to use bootstrap's customization tool to do just that. Although LESS can be intimidating, it isn't complicated.

Comment: If you, like me, don't like to recompile an ENTIRE bootstrap file overwriting other custom things inside of it, see this solutions which works perfectly fine, and IMO better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse

Comment: If you're so coupled to a specific version of CSS @QuantumHive, say goodbye to re-usability without bloat.

Answer (score 16):

here is the solution for sassy people

```
@media(max-width:$screen-sm-max) {
 .navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

why to break a grid when you simply override it with media queries, e.g in sass

```
.navbar-toggle{  
    @media(max-width:$screen-sm-max) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```