# Bootstrap nav collapse - Menu items not aligning in toggle dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I implemented this [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)
to change the navbar collapse but I am having a problem with the toggle on the nav.

I put in this for min-width: 992px to make my menu hover open rather than toggle for desktop sizes.

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu { 
display: block; 
}              /* adding hover effect to bs navbar only for md size and up */

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
text-align: right;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I toggle a menu item  in the sm size. The dropdown menu doesn't toggle directly below. It goes off to the right hand side. I can't seem to find what is the css selector that is putting it directly below while the other items "move out of the way"

This is what is happening

[image: bootstrap menu dropdown]

I want this for sm-size

[image: bootstrap menu dropdown]

Tried to insert my code into bootply... it doesn't collapse properly on there though???
http://www.bootply.com/Q2fqP7kfAK

Comment: put a http://www.bootply.com/new# together with your code to replicate the problem.

Comment: tried to put in the css with bootply. It doesn't even collpase properly as default thought??? http://www.bootply.com/Q2fqP7kfAK

Comment: this dropdown works for me; but it does not display the problem you claim to have.

Comment: this bootply menu doesn't collapse at 991px for me. Does it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the css for changing the collapse had a

```
.navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
```

that caused it to drift off to the side until it hit xs! Removed it and it's a-ok

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set width for `a` tag

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
     text-align: right;
     width : 100%;
}
```