# Bootstrap Navbar collapse not working on iPad (portrait view)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar collapse in smartphones but not colapse in ipad (portrait view).
I wish it also happened on ipad.

1 - On iphone:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/csOj8.png

2 - On ipad:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLAXf.png

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Torpedo Gratis</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Termos de uso</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvz8koyh/

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse

Comment: I'm no expert but try to use different viewport-commands.
Link to Safari(-webkit) viewport commands can be found: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972