# Where to edit bootstrap @grid-float-breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that you can change @grid-float-breakpoint in the "variables.less" file which compiles into the bootstrap package we all download and use (I think).

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

My question is can you change the @grid-float-breakpoint without customising a new bootstrap package, but instead change it through CSS with @media or some other method. If possible please advice the method of where and how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Recompiling the Less source is The Right Way and much easier.

Comment: I am currently using <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">... so when you mean recompile, do you mean customising a new package from bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and refer to a path in my drive?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are 2 recommended main and *different* ways to change the @grid-float-breakpoint (this is a variable in LESS).

1. You can download the master (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip), open the bootstrap.com/variables.less file and then *compile* that with a LESS compiler. *This involves installing a LESS compiler on your computer, such as Grunt (multi-platform) or CodeKit (Mac).*

[image]

2. **OR** Go to [getbootstrap.com/customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) and change the variable there and download a compiled CSS file.

[image]

Comment: To avoid confusion, I'd make note that Grunt in itself is not a compiler, but a task runner that you can load compilation tasks into!

Answer (score 21):

Here is a link to a **css-only** solution to change the grid-float-breakpoint: 
[CSS-Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

Just change 991px by 1199px for md sizes

Of cause the comment to my posting, I have copy-pasted the css-solution behind my link above. 
I have overtaken the solution in my app (MVC6 RC) to set another float-breakpoint (only by apply the .css-style).
Note: im MVC6, you have to add another @ before media (@@media).

Comment: Worked for me in 2020 within an old ASP.NET Webforms project. I placed it directly in the .aspx file. Ugly but it did the job. I appreciate you taking the time to post the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the SASS version, you'll find that variable in bootstrap/_variables.scss around line 286 and onward.

The further you go down that file, the more math and options you'll see.

I post that because people might come here looking for the SASS answer.

It really is better to recompile your file, but if you are making exceptions to rules, it might be better to make a new ID or CLASS to refer to whatever you are doing.