# Bootstrap : How to change the breakpoint where the navbar collapse ?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm a beginner in bootstrap and I try to change the break-point position to make my navbar collapse earlier. (something like 810px instead of the 768px default value).

I searched for the solution through the most of asked questions, but as bootstrap evolves every day, the solutions are deprecated and they don't work anymore.

What I try to do is to modify the `variable.less` file in the `less` directory of Bootstrap.

I changed the file like that :

```
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:     810px;
```

Then I recompiled the file `bootstrap.less` in `bootstrap`.css using `lessc` with this command line :

`lessc bootstrap.less > bootstrap.css` so a new file bootstrap.css have been created in my folder. I simply replaced the default bootstrap.css with the recompiled file bootstrap.css, but nothing change on my website, my navbar always collapse at 768px...

Anyone can help ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092929/where-to-edit-bootstrap-grid-float-breakpoint

Comment: This might not really answer your question, but if you want to customize bootstrap in an easy way, try the [bootstrap live customizer](http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/) it is very helpful :)

Comment: Check to ensure your CSS has definitely been updated. Sounds like it hasn't.

Comment: Thanks both of you, this is a great solution to use the boostrap live customizer. But I don't understand why  it still doesn't work... I have changed the `@grid-float-breakpoint` value and download the new file, I replace all of my files in my project. And nothing happens.

Comment: And the variable.less file has definetely been updated. I'm seeing : `@grid-float-breakpoint:     820px;`

But what is strange is that I don't see any presence of the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in my bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm stupid, I was replacing the wrong folders in the bootstrap folder of my project. Now that I have replaced the right folders in bootstrap/dist everything is ok !

Thanks for sharing the Bootstrap live customizer, it is very helpful and nice to use.