# Enabling BootStrap navbar-collapsed button without zooming

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My navbar have been populated with elements now and it looks too long. Almost touching the navbar-brand. How can i enable the collapsed button without zooming on my browser? I would like to hide the elements on 100% view for cleanliness. I tried some work around but didn't get the result I wanted. I've tried using "collapsed" class on the collapse button but no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep Bootstrap 3.3.x navbar collapsed at all viewport sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581832/keep-bootstrap-3-3-x-navbar-collapsed-at-all-viewport-sizes)

Comment: Answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581832/keep-bootstrap-3-3-x-navbar-collapsed-at-all-viewport-sizes

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time searching for this.