# Bootstrap wrap menu elements at 960px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have small issue. When width page is 768-991px, my menu wrap into second line. I want to browser show button for collapse menu. How can i do it?

There is a link for project: http://interpages.pl/ftp/projects/fremel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question, it may have what your looking for: [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

It mentions specifically problems with overflowing content.