# My bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint wont change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media, breakpoints

i am trying to make my bootstrap navbar collapse if the webpage width is under 1024px but it collapses under 700ish pixels width. I have tried alot of solutions that i googeled but no luck. I have tryed CSS from this post "[Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)" it has a problem similar to mine. But no matter what i do i just wont collapse after 1024px width. I have tryed copying their html(boostrap navbar)+css just to see if that will work but no luck.

My CSS

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)  {
    ul.nav.navbar-nav{
    margin-left:-15px;
}
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

My Bootstrap navbar

```
<nav>
<img class="kopakuttlogo" src="kopakuttlogo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="400" height="400"/>
<div class="navigatsioon">
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    </div>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="http://www.haaboja.ee/" class="active">AVALEHT</a></li>
         <li><a href="Hinnakiri.php">HINNAKIRI</a></li>
         <li><a href="Renditingimused.php">RENDITINGIMUSED</a></li>
        <li><a href="tehnika.php">TEHNIKA</a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.php"></span>KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>



        </li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navigatsioon -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i got it to work with adding .navigatsioon everywhere

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)  {
    .navigatsioon ul.nav.navbar-nav{
    margin-left:-15px;
}
   .navigatsioon .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
   .navigatsioon .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
   .navigatsioon .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navigatsioon .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navigatsioon .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap. How to change the navbar collapse breakpoint**

1. Go to the [Customize page / Grid system](http://www.getbootstrap.sk/customize/#grid-system) and set in the field `@grid-float-breakpoint` the value that you need.
2. Click the `Compile and Download` button at the bottom of the page.
3. Extract the files `bootstrap.css` and  `bootstrap.min.css` from the resulting archive.
4. Use them instead of the standard files `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` on your site.

Nothing else is needed.