# How to change the collapse-menu break-point in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the default collapse break-point in Bootstrap from SM to MD.

I am following [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse?lq=1) .

I have already edited the break-point from here: 
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=b43c00aeea0170543992397b934d496d

Also I have the following link: https://gist.github.com/b43c00aeea0170543992397b934d496d and can be revisited here at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=b43c00aeea0170543992397b934d496d

In addition I can download a zip file with a lot of css styles etc.

**My question is,What is the following step? 
How can I import my change to my project? What should I import?**

Thanks

Comment: I think you just replace what you're using now with the new .css files in the zip download. Either bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: @ourmandave that is an option. However, If I do that, the website speed will decrease. Also... I have checked all the files and I can't find any file with my change

Concretely with this change

>@grid-float-breakpoint 
>@screen-md-min

Comment: Are you sure you changed the values on the configure? I looked at the gist.github.com link and the `@screen-xs` (etc) breakpoints are all standard bootstrap values. Also, why would your site speed decrease if you're swapping css files that are for the most part the same?