# Bootstrap two navbars - second navbar not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have two navbars, a fix-top and the second one just below the 1st one. The 2sd navbar has a greater number of navbar items than the first navbar. If you resize the viewport a little bigger than a phone size, some of the second navbar items will drop into a second row of the 2sd navbar. In this case I want the 2sd navbar to be responsive and collapses its items. At least I do not want the 2sd navbar to grows its height.  Please http://www.bootply.com/cGgFHrlpQn

Comment: i think you need to add a new media query for the 2nd navbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Comment: Both navbars collape at the same time for me, it's just that because the second bar has too many items they drop down to a second "line" before the collapse breakpoint. I suggest you make the navbar collapse earlier then default. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse#20249415