# Bootstrap navbar behind content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, nav

I'm making a web page using bootstrap and i have encountered the following problem with the navbar and the content of the page overlapping. When viewing the page normally everything works fine but the problem occurs when displayed on mobile and a tablet.

What I want to achieve is that when the dropdown button for the navbar is clicked I want the rest of the content to move down. I don't just want to overlay the content with the navbar.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-centered" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid glavni-meni">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MNZ Maribor</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="">Tekmovanja</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Klubi</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Reprezentance</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Grassroots</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Klub Klubu</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Obrazci in predpisi</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Trenerji in sodniki</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Delegati</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Razno</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Ugodnosti</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

      <!--Main content of page-->
      <section id="main-content">
        <div class="container nekaj">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 navigation">
            content content content content content content content content content content content content
          </div>
          <!--Beginning of carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-10 galery">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="Chicago">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="New York">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

And my **CSS:**

```
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  >li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggle{
  border-color: #002d68 !important;
  background-color: #ffff01 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #ffff01 !important;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  background-color: #002d68 !important;
}

.navbar-brand{
  color: #002d68 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffff01;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #002d68 !important;
}

.glavni-meni {
  background-color: #ffff01;
}



#main-content{
  background-image: url('../img/football-field.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And my **mobile CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-centered .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-centered .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-centered .nav>li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-centered .nav>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .container-fluid {
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to make the menu appear above the page content you can use `z-index` in CSS here's the documentation [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For your first problem.**

The navbar appears on top of content ( better say content is under navbar ) because `.navbar-default` has a `height:40px`. You should use `height:auto`. Add a specific path to overwrite the bootstrap css  like `body .navbar-default`

**For second problem**

To change the breaking point of the mobile navbar ( to appear earlier than `768px` ) you should use this code : [change navbar breakpoint](https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint) ( look at bootstrap 3.1 )

In the below example navbar will appear at `1200px` breakpoint

I included the code in the snippet below or > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33787/)

```css
body .navbar-default  {
 height:auto!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  >li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggle{
  border-color: #002d68 !important;
  background-color: #ffff01 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #ffff01 !important;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  background-color: #002d68 !important;
}

.navbar-brand{
  color: #002d68 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffff01;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #002d68 !important;
}

.glavni-meni {
  background-color: #ffff01;
}



#main-content{
  background-image: url('../img/football-field.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-centered .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-centered .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-centered .nav>li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navbar-centered .nav>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .container-fluid {
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-centered" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid glavni-meni">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MNZ Maribor</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="">Tekmovanja</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Klubi</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Reprezentance</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Grassroots</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Klub Klubu</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Obrazci in predpisi</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Trenerji in sodniki</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Delegati</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Razno</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Ugodnosti</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>

      <!--Main content of page-->
      <section id="main-content">
        <div class="container nekaj">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 navigation">
            content content content content content content content content content content content content
          </div>
          <!--Beginning of carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-10 galery">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="Chicago">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="New York">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: this works perfectly :3 thak you mysterious internet stranger ^^

Comment: Good answer, but could I encourage you not to use all-lower-case for stylistic effect? Posts are much more readable with the correct use of upper-case letters. [Useful reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ), [Useful reading 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350604/why-first-person-singular-lowercase).

Comment: @halfer, thanks ! I'll keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: Please do @MihaiT, I will bookmark your profile. Have you written all 432 of your answers in this fashion? That's a lot of extra work for volunteer editors. At the very least I'd like to you fix this one, as a show of goodwill.

Comment: Have a look at the links I've supplied, and see what the community thinks, perhaps? In a community, the views of other people are usually regarded as important. There's nothing authoritarian about my remark, so I've reported your comment for a moderator to look at. I'm not looking to offend you, nor for a fight. I care about the quality of the material here.

Comment: @halfer you should take a break and chill . Don't get so hyped up about some lower case letters. And in case you didn't notice, i edited my answer.