# Bootstrap mobile menu instantly collapse back

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

I need add mobile menu toggle to 990px with bootstrap v3.3.7.

This changes my navbar breakpoint. But when I click menu button it shows menu list an instantly collapse back. So menu doesn't stay open after button is clicked.

How can I do  to menu stay open after button is clicked?

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: post the navbar html as well

Comment: It will Easy to understand if you can provide fiddle or snippet...

Comment: Yes, you can see https://jsfiddle.net/gemex1gv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It is necessary to add the following class:

```
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the fiddle you posted , you should organize it according to bootstrap, and follow there guidelines.

Comment: Thank you Nikola,  could you give me an example please?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192082/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse . You are missing this code     .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }  on max-width 990px